# Change requirements for passwords on Oracle Solaris 11.2

Tags: solaris, password, accounts

Is it possible to change strict requirements for user passwords, including root, e.g. I'd like not include numbers in the password as required, since this is a home machine, and I'm the only user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Solaris, password constraints can be configured by editing the `/etc/default/password` file , eg:

```
$ pfedit /etc/default/password
...
MINDIGIT=0
...
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Is it a common practice to edit config files with pfedit then vi ?

Comment: There is no need to use `pfedit` then `vi`, just one of these will do. `pfedit` would be the best practice leveraging Solaris RABC and will use the configured editor for the user, `vi` by default. If you are already logged as root, directly running `vi` will obviously still work.